# Changing Data Type of Values in Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a program which reads a file and converts the contents into a dictionary (d). The values all come in as a string. The value of each key is a list containing two elements. Both of these elements are numbers and I wish to store them as floats. I'm having a hard time finding how I can access this specific part of each value-list in the dictionary to change it.

My code is:

```
d = {'apples':['100.0','23.5'], 'bananas':['41.5','321.0'], ... 'mango':['2.0','431.0']}
```

Whereas I would like:

```
d = {'apples':[100.0, 23.5], 'bananas':[41.5, 321.0], ... 'mango':[2.0, 431.0]}
```

These values are meant to be stored as floats as some division follows later

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
d = {'apples':['100.0','23.5'], 'bananas':['41.5','321.0'], 'mango':['2.0','431.0']}
dict={}
for i in d:
    dict[i]=[]
    for j in d[i]:
        dict[i].append(float(j))


print(dict)
```

It will generate new dictionary which values are float type